# bootstrap css for input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field that I would like to use bootstrap alert css class.The problem is that 
I can't get that to work because bootstrap also defines more specific selector `input[type="text"]`.So, is that it? I can forget using that alert css class on input elements ? I would really like to avoid creating more specific css rule just for input fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "forget it", but you will have to touch a bit of CSS (or LESS actually).

You can managed to do most of the work with LESS mixins :

```css
input.myInputAlert {    
  .alert;
}
```

which gives roughly the following

```css
input.myInputAlert {
  /* padding: 8px 35px 8px 14px; */
  /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border: 1px solid #fbeed5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #c09853;
}
```

And I removed the padding and margin rule to let it use the real `input` values.

And without testing much, it does look like it's working : http://jsbin.com/oqoqeg/2

---

You can see about LESS compiling [there (lesscss.org)](http://lesscss.org/#usage)

Comment: Wow, great.I was lazy to check out LESS, but after this I sure will.